# How to configure the following parameters in IEEEtran template

Tags: formatting, margins, line-spacing, ieeetran, ieeeconf

I have a latex paper using the IEEEtran template.
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
The paper is two columns by default. How can I configure the following parameters:

1. Columns length: 9.5 in.
2. Columns with: 3.5 in.
3. Text is Times font.
4. Line spacing is 11-point.

- 

Comment: `IEEEtran` is meant for submissions to IEEE journals or conferences. Why would you need those changes?

Comment: I want to make sure that using [conference] complies with the [conference,compsoc] measurements. Because using compsoc exceeds the pages limit.